# How do i make a circuit with 3 different counters that count 3 different things?

Tags: circuit-design, logic-gates

The system requires 3 counters
-one for the number of pills per bottle
-the number of bottles filled
-the total number of pills in the final bottles.

Comment: Homework?  What have you done so far?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: yea, it's a project..well so far I created two separate circuits and counters for the number of pills entered and number of bottles, however, I forgot that I needed 3 counters in basically one circuit and I'm not sure how to do that tbh

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a homework problem with no effort shown.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding the question. It sounds like you're asking us, "How do I put 3 counters in a circuit?" But the answer to that question seems pretty obvious: "Put a counter in, then put another counter in, then put another counter in." Is there something preventing you from putting more counters in? What am I missing?

Comment: my main problem was that I did not know how to put 3 counters in one circuit and make all of them function properly but I figured it out eventually.  I'm closing this question because you people are just very, I don't even know the word to use but you guys just assumed I did nothing at all and asked you guys to do everything for me, I just wanted simple advice.

Comment: @intenselysuffering - Hi, I'm sorry that you seem unhappy. As a specifically Q&A site, Stack Exchange works best with questions that include what has been attempted so far, so that site members don't waste your time (and theirs) explaining things you already know. You said: "*you [...] just assumed I did nothing at all*" From your viewpoint it might seem like that. However you didn't show any block diagrams etc. of your work so far, so members here simply didn't know where to carry on from :-( That is why, especially for homework-type questions, we need to know *exactly* where you are stuck.

Comment: [continued] For the future, I recommend you have a look at the site [tour] and [help] to see more info about the site, its rules and etiquette. There are a lot of helpful people here, if you give them a chance, and if you can help them to help you by explaining *exactly* where you are stuck. Without those details, even though *you* know what you've done, it can seem to readers that you are asking them to do your whole project. See what I mean? Anyway, good luck with the project.

Comment: @intenselysuffering I said with no effort *shown*, not no effort done. Rules of the site are that homework questions need to show what you've done up to this point, or else they'll be closed. That should be in the new-user information you should have been linked to when you created your account. In addition to what Sam said above (we need to know where you *are* to know what you should do next!), regardless of what you personally intended, the fact is there are countless people who try to use this site to cheat on homework, and we don't want to allow that.

Comment: well, that is understandable, this is my first time posting a question and I didn't expect to actually get feedback cause I see a lot of questions go unanswered so I just threw out the question in a sense of little hope but I was not exactly counting on it so I forgot to add the diagrams I had.

Comment: @intenselysuffering: (and anyone else new to stack exchange) -- if you were hurt by the quick vote to close, well, StackExchange will _reopen_ a question that's been modified to be up to community standards.  So -- in this community at least -- it's not a slap in the face, just a thing that happens.

Comment: You should also indicate what the constraints are on your solution? What types of parts are you allowed to use. In the real world you'd probably solve this with a microcontroller. In Homework-world you might be required to use discrete logic, or an FPGA, or bare transistors...or whatever your instructor specified. You need to tell us what that constraint is for us to be able to give you a useful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: You can use a set of 4017B counter ICs and logic gates ICs for testing conditions/comparisons, to answer your questions. I don't have enough point to leave the hint as a comment. So I give it here.